# Template Tags Not Loading in Apache

Tags: python, html, django, apache, django-templates

So I have a very elementary Django application. I have deployed the application using the development server and my page seems to render completely fine without any hiccups. However, as soon as I try to run it on the Apache server the HTML page serves but the underlying template tags are not.

Below is my Apache configuration:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ec2-user/website/bash/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/ec2-user/website
<Directory "/home/ec2-user/website/bash/">
    <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /home/ec2-user/website/static

<Directory "/home/ec2-user/website/static">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The only template tags that I'm using are tags to serve static files. Here's my settings.py configurations:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'landing',
    'home',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'home/','static/'), '/static/')

SITE_MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'home/', 'templates/', 'home')
```

I know that it's not rendering because my access logs in Apache are just showing the escaped character key values for the template tag.

```
[20/Dec/2015:14:00:37 +0000] "GET /%7B%%20static HTTP/1.1" 400 226
[20/Dec/2015:14:00:38 +0000] "GET /%7B%%20static HTTP/1.1" 400 226
[20/Dec/2015:14:05:08 +0000] "GET /%7B%%20static HTTP/1.1" 400 226
[20/Dec/2015:14:05:09 +0000] "GET /%7B%%20static HTTP/1.1" 400 226
[20/Dec/2015:14:19:10 +0000] "GET /%7B%%20static HTTP/1.1" 400 226
[20/Dec/2015:14:19:12 +0000] "GET /%7B%%20static HTTP/1.1" 400 226
[20/Dec/2015:14:25:35 +0000] "GET /%7B%%20static HTTP/1.1" 400 226
[20/Dec/2015:14:25:36 +0000] "GET /%7B%%20static HTTP/1.1" 400 226
[20/Dec/2015:14:25:49 +0000] "GET /%7B%%20static HTTP/1.1" 400 226
[20/Dec/2015:14:25:50 +0000] "GET /%7B%%20static HTTP/1.1" 400 226
```

Here is my HTML template code, please don't mind the poor code!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        {% load staticfiles %}

        <title> Home </title>
        <link href="{% static "css/style_file.css" %}" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{% static "media/hat.png" %}" />
    </head>

    <body>


        <div class="container">


                <div id="logo"> <img src="{% static "media/title.png" %}" alt="title"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I'm utterly lost and have no idea where I've gone wrong. I know that I'm generally serving the pages alright because in the development server the view function is serving the template as expected. What am I doing wrong in the Apache server!

Edit: Checked further and this issue seems to only be there over port 80. Even when I use the development server over that port it's not loading the corresponding tags and/or static elements.

Comment: And just to add it seems to only be happening over port 80. When I run the dev server on any other port it all renders, only port 80 to get those rendering problems.

Comment: you can edit your description instead of adding in comments so that the problem is clear to everyone.

Comment: I'm surprised you are getting a 400 response. Have you set `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in your settings?

Comment: I did set it to '*'.

Comment: What URL are you going to when you see this? And what does your project's urls.py look like?

Comment: Using the root URL. So direct http://public-ip:80 or just http://public-ip. Thought it might be a problem with the URLs files but here's my project's urls.py:

`from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('home.urls')),
]`

And my app urls.py:

`from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from project import settings

urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed ownership and the TINIEST of syntax errors. Needed a trailing slash after the "/home/ec2-user/website/static**/**".